# Knockout and JQueryUI binding does not call update callback

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

When creating foreach binding with custom one, the "update:" callback is not being called when pushing new element to view model.
However, new span(not accordion) item is creating.

```
<div data-bind="foreach:items, koAccordion: {}">
<div>
<span data-bind="text: id"></span>
</div>
<div>
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

The script:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.koAccordion = {
         init:function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel,bindingContext) {
                console.log("INITIALIZATION CALLBACK");
                $(element).accordion();
            },
    update:function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
                console.log("UPDATING CALLBACK");
                $(element).accordion('destroy').accordion();
            }
    };
function Item(id,name,description){
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.description = ko.observable(description);
}


var viewModel = {
    items:ko.observableArray([new Item("New Id","New Name","New Description")]),
    addItem:function(id,name,description){
        viewModel.items.push(new Item(id,name,description))
    }    
};


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binding's `update()` function is called when its dependencies change.

That means you must trigger knockout's dependency tracking inside the body of `update()`. This happens generally by producing the underlying value of an observable (in other words, by calling it).

Normally you would also use that value inside the function, but in this case you only need that step so the dependency tracking notices that there is a subscriber.

This will work:

```html
<!--                                         pass observable here -->
<div data-bind="foreach: items, koAccordion: items">
    <div>
        <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
ko.bindingHandlers.koAccordion = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).accordion();

        // properly destroy the widget when the element gets removed
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            $(element).accordion('destroy');
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // unwrap the observable: this registers an implicit subscription
        ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        $(element).accordion('refresh');
    }
};
```

But in essence you can skip the `update` callback entirely and use an explicit subscription instead:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.koAccordion = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var items = valueAccessor(),
            subscription;

        $(element).accordion();

        // set up an explicit subscription
        subscription = items.subscribe(function () {
            $(element).accordion('refresh');
        });

        // properly destroy the widget when the element gets removed
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
            subscription.dispose();
            $(element).accordion('destroy');
        });
    }
};
```

---

That being said, there is a mature jQueryUI custom binding library that you should use, instead of rolling your own: http://gvas.github.io/knockout-jqueryui/

Comment: Don't forget to check out knockout-jqueryui, it is a lot better than what I have written here.